# Substring helper in handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, substring, helper

Can i write a helper in Handlebars that can tell if a string is a substring of another string?

I wrote the following code, but it doesn't seem to be working

This is the helper:

```
'if_sub': function(a, b, opts) {
     if (a.includes(b))
         return opts.fn(this);
     else
         return opts.inverse(this);
 }
```

And this is the implementation:

```
{{#if_sub colvalues "success"}}
    <td class="log-success"> {{colvalues}} </td>
{{/if_sub}}
```

Comment: what is `colvalues` ? is it string ?

Comment: @Mahi yes. It's a variable which contains a string. For example- "failure: txn1".

Comment: so if variable `colvalues ` has `succ` then it should return ` opts.fn(this);` else `opts.inverse(this);` ??

Comment: @Mahi Yes something like this. But i don't know if i am implementing this correctly. Can you please guide a little bit as to how it should be?

Comment: @Mahi It throws an error saying "Object has no method 'includes'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just little mistake . `if (a.includes(b))` should be `if (b.includes(a))`

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>How to render html with Handlebars.js</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/handlebarsjs/4.0.3/handlebars.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"    type="text/javascript"></script>
 
  <script id="simple-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

      {{#if_sub colvalues "success"}}
    <td class="log-success">  {{colvalues}} </td>
      {{/if_sub}}
  </script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
        Handlebars.registerHelper("if_sub",function(a, b, opts) {

     if (b.includes(a)){
       return opts.fn(this);
     }
         
     else{
       return opts.inverse(this);
     }
         
 });
  
    //wait for page to load
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var raw_template = $('#simple-template').html();
      var template = Handlebars.compile(raw_template);
      var data = {colvalues:"suc"}; //change value and see.
      var html = template(data);
      $('#main').append(html);

    });
  </script>
</head>
  
<body>
<!-- Insertion point for handlebars template -->
<div id="main" style="margin-left:100px">
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I get this error. " Object success has no method 'includes' "

Comment: then i don't know why you are getting problem ..  maybe `{colvalues:"suc"};` instead of `"suc"` you are giving object. and Object doesn't have include method . array does

Comment: Ok let me check this out. Thanks for your time. :)

Comment: Figured out the error. The {{colvalue}} that was passed was an object. Converted it to string and it worked. Thanks a lot for your patience :)

Comment: nice,how did you convert object to string ??

Comment: 'if_in': function(str, value, options) {
                                    if(str.toString().indexOf(value) !== -1) 
                                        return options.fn(this);
                                    else
                                        return options.inverse(this);
                                }